# fovis_ros with kinect get no odom result

Tags: ros, kinect, fovis, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm now using fovis_ros to do visual odometry,  i can get the topic /camera/rgb/image_rect,  /camera/depth_register/image_rect, but Synchronized tuples was zero. And i can't get the visual odometry data.   I don't know why?  hope please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115751/fovis_ros--with-kinect-get-no-odom-result/) by [lemontr085](https://answers.ros.org/users/10576/lemontr085/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-01-16**:
Hi lemontr085, can you post here more details on what else you launch appart from fovis_ros? A list of all the nodes or processes launched, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check this [Question](http://answers.ros.org/question/166176/problem-with-fovis/)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0